# vue3 can I cange composition api ref type?

Tags: vue.js, ref, vue-composition-api

if I have a props.id array like this from father component to prop another components

```
<components id="1"></components >
<components id="2"></components >
<components id="3"></components >
```

could I base on this props.id to change my ref type like this?

```
<script set-up>
    import { ref, defineProps} ... 
    const props = defineProps({
        id: Number
    })
    const state = {
         data: props.id === 3 ? ref([]) : ref({})
    }
</script set-up>
```

Comment: It's incorrect to make it depend on a prop because prop values can be updated. A more reasonable way is to have two refs and switch between them depending on a prop. Consider explaining your case, maybe it would make more sense to have a single normalized state

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry I look at your answer now. Thank your answer! I do another ways to fix it~ thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the default value by the props.

```js
const state = ref(props.id === '1' ? [] : {});
```

And I recommend using `reactive` instead `ref` if you want to watch an object.

Comment: thanks bro. You help me! I use reactive better than use ref.